# How to rotate an array by ± 180° in an efficient way?

Tags: python, optimization

What is the best algorithm to rotate a non-square M×N array by 180° around its center, using the least memory and operations, for C langages and derivatives (Python, Cython, pure C) ?

Comment: Which language, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I program mainly in Python

Comment: Are you asking for a simple np.flip()?

Comment: @sascha I'm asking for a low-level logic to implement inside a C/Cython module, not for a package function.

Comment: Then why compare with numpy's rot90? np.flip is constant time.

Comment: Because I don't understand how they do better than my code using Python slices.

Comment: Because they don't write/change any entry. They are just setting flags which will make evaluation different when accessed. It's a view!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161758/discussion-between-aurelien-pierre-and-sascha).

Comment: The rotation by 180° is called **reverse**. Do you mean rotation by 90°?

Comment: reverse if you wish, whatever the name is, I mean 180°

Comment: So, the answer below is incorrect as it shows the rotation by 90°.

Comment: The `numpy.flip` performs the reverse.

Comment: if `b` is the output of my function below, `np.all(np.isclose(np.rot90(a, 2), b)) == True`. So this is 2 rotations of 90°.

Comment: But `np.all(np.isclose(np.rot90(a, 2), np.flip(a, 0))) == False`. so this is not what I want.

Comment: actually, `np.flip` is a symmetry along an axis.

Comment: @AurélienPierre: You forget to flip the second axis. Rotation by 180 degrees is the same as the flip along both axes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming `out` is an initialized copy of `array`, `M` and `N` their rows and columns numbers, and we are using a language indexing arrays from 0 to (M-1) and (N-1) :

In Python :

```
def rotate_180(array, M, N, out):
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            out[i, N-1-j] = array[M-1-i, j]
```

This takes 5.82 s on a 4000×3000 array.

In parallelized Cython + OpenMP using Memviews :

```
cdef void rotate_180(float[:, :] array, int M, int N, float[:, :] out) nogil:

    cdef size_t i, j

    with parallel(num_threads=8):
        for i in prange(M):
            for j in range(N):
                out[i, N-1-j] = array[M-1-i, j]
```

This takes 5.45 s on a 4000×3000 array.

In comparison, numpy with `np.rot90(array, 2)` takes 8.58 µs.

**Edit : to avoid know-it-all comments out of the point, here is what it does :**

```
a = array([[1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 8, 9]])

rotate_180(a, 3, 3, b)

b = array([[9, 8, 7],
           [6, 5, 4],
           [3, 2, 1]])
```

Using 2 successive 90° rotations with numpy built-in function, we get :

```
np.rot90(a, 2)

out = array([[9, 8, 7],
             [6, 5, 4],
             [3, 2, 1]])
```

So this `rotate_180()` is indeed a 180° rotation. Now :

```
np.flip(a, 0)

out = array([[7, 8, 9],
             [4, 5, 6],
             [1, 2, 3]])
```

is not a rotation but a symmetry along the last line. If we compose 2 symmetries along each direction :

```
np.flip(np.flip(a, 1), 0)

out = array([[9, 8, 7],
             [6, 5, 4],
             [3, 2, 1]])
```

we also get a 180° rotation.

So, yes, thank you, my code does what it says.

Answer (score 9):

It's relatively late to answer this question but still better than doing nothing.

For 2D numpy arrays being in shape of `H x W`:

```
rotated_array = old_array[::-1,::-1] #rotate the array 180 degrees
```

For 2D numpy images being in shape of `H x W x 3`:

```
rotated_image = image[::-1,::-1] #rotate the image 180 degrees
```